# MIME type not working for SVG

Tags: html, svg, mime-types, aptana, meta

I am trying to embed a `.svg` file into my webpage (which I am editting with Aptana). The piece of code needed is

```
<img src="pict.svg" width=800px/>
```

It works perfectly when internally ran with Aptana. But when trying in the localhost or when deploying it to internet, I only get the following icon:

[image]

Somewhere I have read it has to do with declaring MIME type, and namely it is recommended to write the following piece of code in the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="image/svg+xml">
```

But nothing changes. Perhaps it has to do with Aptana... for instance, one can change the text encoding without using

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

which makes me think that something similar may happen with the `.svg` files.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure it is not just firing an 404 Not found?

Comment: @brance No, remember that it works perfectly when ran from Aptana.

Comment: Try to modify your htaccess file, like I've posted it underneath.

Comment: @brance It sounds right... but I have never dealt with .htaccess before... Should I create a .htaccess file associated to my .html file? How?

Comment: I've edited my answer, just create a new file named .htaccess and add the code to it.

Comment: @brance The .htaccess file... is created with Aptana?

Comment: Using Notepad, create a empty new document, and save the file as .htaccess then reopen it and add the code to it, and save it again.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to your .htaccess file, add this line of code to it and save it.

```
AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
```

That should fix your problem.

EDIT: How to create a htaccess file.

Just go to the folder where your index.html or index.php file is located (you homepage), and create a new file `.htaccess`, and just add the code from above to it and save it.

Comment: .htaccess is an Apache thing.  I don't think it will work with Aptana/Eclipses' built in web server.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to check:

1. Open your browser dev tools. Go to the Net/Network tab and load the page.  You should be able to see from the responses what the MIME type being returned is.  Look for the "Type" column in Chrome, or in Firefox click the plus sign and look for the "Content-type" response header.
2. What does your SVG file look like?  Standalone SVG files have some basic requirements that inlined SVGs don't.  The main thing is to check that your SVG file has an `xmlns` in its root `<svg>` element.

   ```
   <svg ... xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ... >
   ```